# MySql 5.7 Deadlock with a next-key lock on a non-unique index and Read-Committed isolation level

Tags: mysql, isolation-level, database-deadlocks

In mysql 5.7 documentation, it says that for READ-COMMITTED isolation level, there wouldn't be any next-key locks or gap locks placed on an update query. 
But I'm getting frequent deadlocks for the following query.

> UPDATE customer SET status ='SUCCESS' WHERE subscriber_id IN (146,148,150,152,153,154,155,156,157,158)

The subscriber_id is an indexed field but not unique.

When I checked for the innodb status following was found.

> **For the first transaction**
>
> (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
>   RECORD LOCKS space id 57008 page no 6 n bits 224 index subscriber_id
>   of table `customer`.`subscriber_id` /* Partition `monthly_rest` */ trx
>   id 1340735 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
>
> Record lock, heap no 144 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format;    > info bits 0
>   0: len 8; hex 8000000000000093; asc         ;;
>   1: len 5; hex 999b870acb; asc      ;;
>
> **For the second transaction**
>
> *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S): RECORD LOCKS space id 57008 page no 6 n bits 224 index subscriber_id of table
>   `customer`.`subscriber_id` /* Partition `monthly_rest` */ trx id
>   1340730 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
>
> Record lock, heap no 136
>   PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
>   0: len 8; hex 8000000000000093; asc         ;;
>   1: len 5; hex 999b870acb; asc    ;;

I've only put an excerpt of the lock details here.

It seems like the subscriber_id field has been locked with a next-key lock.

Is it possible even with READ-COMMITTED in mysql 5.7 to get a next-key lock ?

Could that be due to using a non-unique key ?

It would be an immense help if someone can provide an explanation

Comment: Many questions get "noisy" when people paste too much, but I think it might be best if you don't redact anything, here.  Based on what is shown, it appears that the contention is over a lock on the row for 0x93 (decimal 147) which does suggest a next-key lock, since that value isn't here.  Consider adding the full output in case there is something else that may be useful -- it seems like there must be.

Comment: I'll paste the complete output asap. Is it possible in MySql 5.7 to get a next-key lock with an isolation level of READ-COMMITTED ?

Comment: Here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html they write: `UPDATE ... WHERE ... sets an exclusive next-key lock on every record the search encounters. However, only an index record lock is required for statements that lock rows using a unique index to search for a unique row.`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This helped a lot.